# NHibernate Query<T> with detached criteria...

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have that :

```
var query = session.Query<MyClass>();    

// Here I need to execute a detached criteria, like that :
//  query.UnderlyingCriteria.Add(SpatialExpression.Within("Geo", extent));

var t = query.Select(item => new MyClassView
                                      {
                                          Name, Year, Code
                                      }
```

Is that a way to do that with Query ? Or maybe another way? I need a IQueryable result...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the linq provider does not use Criteria under the covers, it uses the AST from the HQL parser. If you really need an IQueryable then you could formulate a query like this

```
var ids = session.QueryOver<MyClass>()
    .UnderlyingCriteria.Add(SpatialExpression.Within("Geo", extent))
    .Select(myclass => myclass.Id)
    .List<int>();

var query = session.Query<MyClass>()
    .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id))
    .Select(item => new MyClassView
    {
        Name, Year, Code
    });
```

Note: this uses 2 roundtrips however

Comment: Thanks, And if I´d like to return IList, using only QueryOver, how can I return IList<MyClassView> ? I tried, but got and error : "Could not determine member from new MyClassView() "

Comment: the only way to project into a DTO with query over looks like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5972357/671619