# Using NHibernate 3 linq provider with NHibernate spatial

Tags: linq, nhibernate, spatial

I'm starting to work with the NHibernate 3 linq provider and it's great.
Until now I've used NHibernate spatial with Criteria.

How do I go about using linq with NHibernate spatial?

Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 0):

i do not know if it is possible out of the box. Either use NH hooks in the linq provider to implement it or do it like i posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9585622/671619

Answer (score 0):

Some time has passed since you originally posted the question but, as you haven't marked it as answered, let me show you a blog post that I've written on the subject, showing several query examples using NH Spatial in HQL and LINQ.

You can check it [here](http://build-failed.blogspot.pt/2012/03/nhibernate-spatial-part-4-querying.html)

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but yes, you can use NHibernate.Spatial in LINQ queries. You'll have to use one of the NHibernate.Spatial forks (eg: the one by @psousa here: https://github.com/pmcxs/Nhibernate.Spatial or the one by @suryapratap here https://github.com/suryapratap/Nhibernate.Spatial).

The supported range of operations can be guessed by looking in the source code at the NHibernate.Spatial.Linq.Functions.SpatialLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry 
source file. For example this code here:

```
public class AnalysisDistanceGenerator : SpatialMethodGenerator<IGeometry, double>
{
    public AnalysisDistanceGenerator() : base(g => g.Distance(null)) { }
}
```

This means you should be able to do a query like this:

```
dbSession.Query<Entity>().Where(x => x.Location.Distance(point) < 50).FirstOrDefault();
```

There's a bug (or actually, it is an oversight in NHibernate's design) that causes queries like that above that take a Point instance to fail with error:

```
ArgumentException: 24204: The spatial reference identifier (SRID) is not valid.
```

This happens because NHibernate tries to find an NHibernate IType instance to use for coverting the "Point" data type (parameter) to SQL and ends up not find anything, so it uses the default SerializableType which doesn't respect the SRID parameter you set on the point instance itself.

The oversight is that NHibernate doesn't natively allow to specify "entity persisters" (which act as type coverters from/to SQL) outside of the default ones that come with it that it self-registers. For loading or saving entities, it uses the metadata defined for the entity that was compiled from the class mappings (hbm/xml, fluent or mapping by code), so that works, but for non-mapped Point instances, it just handles them wrong.

After spending many hours debugging in NHibernate, the solution is simply to make NHibernate treat Point and IPoint instances as though they were a built-in type by registering a IType for it (and then you can define SRID, subtype for it) and it works fine.

Unfortunately, this method uses reflection to access NHibernate.Type.TypeFactory.RegisterType method which is marked private. I was not able to find any public API to reach this method.

Just call this method once during creation of NHibernate SessionFactory (in app startup). Obviously, it makes an assumption that you will use default SRID 4326 for all point parameters that don't explicitly set their SRID. You can pass null for the parameters dictionary instead of specifying default SRID and subtype if you want.

It is ugly, but works perfectly:

```
    static void RegisterGeometryTypeForIPointUsingReflection()
    {
        var methods =
            typeof(TypeFactory).GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

        var requiredOverload = methods.Where(
            x =>
            {
                if (x.Name != "RegisterType") return false;

                var args = x.GetParameters();
                if (args.Length != 2) return false;

                return args[0].ParameterType == typeof(IType)
                       && args[1].ParameterType == typeof(IEnumerable<string>);
            })
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (requiredOverload == null)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException(
                "Could not find TypeFactory.RegisterType method overload in NHibernate. Please report this issue.");
        }

        requiredOverload.Invoke(
            null,
            new object[]
            {
                new CustomType(
                    typeof(GeometryType),
                    new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        { "srid", "4326" },
                        { "subtype", "POINT" }
                    }),
                new[]
                { typeof(IPoint).AssemblyQualifiedName, typeof(Point).AssemblyQualifiedName }
            });
    }
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. I called the method as I create the session factory but then I get a different run-time error.